# How to write a policy where a user can access two resources in XACML?

Tags: authorization, access-control, xacml, abac, alfa

I need to define a policy which has these two requirements:

> (1) Any user can access (read, write, etc.) to the resources `http://www.example.com/info1` and `http://www.example.com/info2`
>
> (2) Any reading action (read) to any resource can only be accessed by users which belong to the group `admin` and `manager`.

This policies must be written in XACML.

Then, what I have solved is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" PolicyId="1" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable" Version="1.0">
    <Description>Policy 1</Description>
    <Target />
    <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="Rule #1" >
        <Target>
            <AnyOf>
                <AllOf>
                    <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-regexp-match">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">http://www.example.com/info1</AttributeValue>
                        <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true" />
                    </Match>
                </AllOf>
                <AllOf>
                    <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-regexp-match">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">http://www.example.com/info2</AttributeValue>
                        <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true" />
                    </Match>
                </AllOf>
            </AnyOf>
        </Target>
    </Rule>
    <!--Punto d.2-->
    <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="Rule #2">
        <Target>
            <AnyOf>
                <AllOf>
                    <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
                        <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true" />
                    </Match>
                </AllOf>
            </AnyOf>
        </Target>
        <Condition>
            <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-at-least-one-member-of">
                <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
                    <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">admin</AttributeValue>
                    <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">manager</AttributeValue>
                </Apply>
                <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="group" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:group" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true" />
            </Apply>
        </Condition>
    </Rule>
</Policy>
```

(Link with syntax highlighting: https://gist.github.com/Fhernd/62c6e387767cc4fc79aead3a669ea4c0)

Does the way I have implemented these two rules are correct? O more precisely, the usage of `AnyOf` is correct for the rule `Rule #1`?, Is it possible to omit the `Condition` element for that rule?

Can I have only a read operation in the `Target>AnyOf>AlloOf` element?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I can combine two rules in single one in XACML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597859/how-do-i-can-combine-two-rules-in-single-one-in-xacml)